CSP https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/v3/security.js
hace unos dias que estoy tratando de implementar Api mercado pago para una ecommerce con React y Node;
Hago que por medio de ngrok que me tire una url para acceder y hacer pruebas desde mercado pago, hago url/auth para pedirle permiso al Vendedor de sus cerdenciales para poder efectuar su pago y cuando ingreso a la cuenta me sale el error "Lo sentimos, la aplicación no puede conectarse a tu cuenta" y en consola muestra:

mi codigo es:
app.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
const redirectUri = "https://559c-2803-9800-9803-ba94-a9bd-c6b3-b5f9-12db.ngrok-free.app/callback";
const authUrl = https://auth.mercadopago.com.ar/authorization?client_id=${mercadoLibreClient.client_id}&response_type=code&platform_id=mp&redirect_uri=${redirectUri};
res.redirect(authUrl);
});
desde ya, gracias! 01/07/2024

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! que tiene que ver php aca?

Hola Alvaro, bienvenido, la pregunta/respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, te sugiero que la edites, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, para que no sea cerrada, y evitar recibir votos negativos,
